# Set default value to an image field form element using form_alter

Tags: 7, entities, media

I am using this code, but the form doesn't get default image value:
The image is created and exists in the server:

```
$image = file_get_contents($url);
$destination = 'image.jpg';
$file = file_save_data($image, $destination, FILE_EXISTS_RENAME);
```

And $form is populated this way:

```
$form['field_user_picture']['und'][0]['value']['#default_value']['fid'] = $file->fid;
```

I think I am missing something, could anybody help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
$form['field_user_picture']['und'][0]['#default_value']['fid'] = $file->fid;
```

(Remove `['value']` key.)